# Dynamically creating label tag with the "for" attribute

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, reserved-words

In HTML, you can assign the "for" attribute of a label tag so that when the user clicks the label, it selects the corresponding radio button:

```
<input type="radio" name="group" value="1" id="radioButtonId" />
<label for="radioButtonId">label text</label>
```

There's problems when creating the label tag dynamically with javascript (specifically with Prototype JS framework). *For* is a reserved keyword for *for loops*. Prototype JS's documentation shows that *className* is the code word for the reserved keyword *class*, but it doesn't say what the code word for *for* is. What is it?

```
new Element(
 'label', {
  for: 'radioButtonId'
 }
).update('label text');
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`className`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-95362176) is the standard DOM property corresponding to the `class` attribute; it's nothing to do with Prototype per se.

Similarly, the DOM property corresponding to the `for` attribute is [`htmlFor`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-96509813).

Answer (score 5):

To use a reserved work as a key in an object literal, just wrap it in quotes, like this:

```
new Element(
 'label', {
  'for': 'radioButtonId'
 }
).update('label text');
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting for in quotes?

```
new Element('label',{'for':'radioButtonId'}).update('label text');
```